# Equivalent of sorted function with compare function in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sorting

This works perfectly in Python 2.7

```
def some_compare_func(x, y):
  ....

a = sorted(some_list, lambda x, y: some_compare_func(x, y))
```

However, the same gives this error in Python 3.x.

```
TypeError: sorted expected 1 arguments, got 2
```

Is there a way to sort with a sorting function that works both in Python 2.7 and 3.x?

Comment: But then it doesn't work with Python 2.7 anymore. Man, this is annoying :(

Comment: Yes, tried it, doesn't work in 2.7. Says TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Can you show an actual minimal reproducible example? you also have to specify the key via a keyword argument like `key = lambda`...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted

Comment: You may want to have a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#the-old-way-using-the-cmp-parameter) that explains how to port code that uses Python 2 sorting to Python 3.

Comment: This how-to article describes a wrapper function that can be used to converted `some_compare_func` to be used in Python 3, although it is designed for porting, not for interoperability https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: the kwarg `cmp=some_compare_function` has been removed in py3. You can use `key`.

Comment: Ah- maybe i misunderstood in py3, you need `functools.cmp_to_key` to the old `cmp=` style sorting (it's very rarely useful though)

Comment: It's much more efficient to sort using a `key` function, rather than a `cmp` function. The former only gets called once per item in the list, but the latter must be called every time a comparison is performed, so it's significantly slower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the python2 style `cmp` to `key` using `functools.cmp_to_key()`

The following code should work both in python2 and python3

```
def some_compare_func(x, y):
  ....

import functools
a = sorted(some_list, key=functools.cmp_to_key(some_compare_func))
```

Check https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#the-old-way-using-the-cmp-parameter for more details

Comment: That is brilliant. Thanks.